# Internet access to host behind firewall using ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, security, firewall, iptables, ssh-tunnel

My goal is to give host behind firewall access to the internet. Below you can find brief description of network

```
[internet] <-> [proxy] <-> [A] <-> (firewall) <-> [B]
```

**[A]** - local linux host with access to network via [proxy] server

**[B]** - remote host behind firewall without access to internet

Host A can access B via ssh.

How can I achieve this using ssh reverse tunneling and iptables on hosts A and B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need a ssh reverse tunnel:

```
-R 8888:proxy:3128
```

where 'proxy' is the hostname or address of the proxy server and 3128 the port where the proxy server is listening for connections. After this any connection to port 8888 in B will be redirected to the proxy server